# Plugin with id 'crashlytics' not found issue with Android studio latest plugin

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

For the following gradle build configuration, I am facing Error:(11, 0) Plugin with id 'crashlytics' not found error.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'
apply plugin: 'hugo'


repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}




android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wiznsystems.android"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/smartconfiglib.jar')
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-runtime:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.+'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.2.1'
    compile 'fr.avianey:facebook-android-api:+@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.+'
    compile 'de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.4'
    compile project(':apptentiveandroidsdk')
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? or Is there any workaround for making it build?

Comment: I have the same problem now. I think it is temporary problem. I hope so)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. What I ended up doing was putting the order of the commands inline with what Crashlytics provided. I had something similar to yours and it didn't work. Once it changed it to the exact order of there docs it worked. Here is what mine looks like now. Hope this helps.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
      classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
  compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
  compile 'com.joanzapata.android:android-iconify:1.0.6'
  compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:0.3.1'
  compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5'
  compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3'
  compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 19
  buildToolsVersion "20"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try informing the classpath dependency:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After battling with this error for hours, I ended up deleting the ".gradle" folder on my home directory, and the issue vanished! So, if you are getting this issue, try deleting the .gradle folder first, then rebuild your project.